# Black hole and the cosmic string

Tags: black-holes, mass-energy, black-hole-thermodynamics, cosmic-string

For a regular black hole, the mass and energy of the black hole are identical（according to first law of black hole thermodynamics),  but for a black hole with a  cosmic string this is not satisfied. why？